# building my models for bluimp image gallery separate image models for each parent model; same model for images and video ... good ideas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to build my models for bluimp (actually bootstrap-image-gallery an extension of bluimp) I have a lot of different models that can have many images Is it better to have separate image models for each of them to make things easier for my server or let them all use the same image model? What about using the same models for images and video (or even just audio) I think the gallery supports videos, I dunno about audio files Are these good ideas? ~ thanks

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord gives you the possibility to define polymorphic associations.
You should take a look to the [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) that is very clear about this common pattern.
Probably is better to split up image and video in two different models. In this way you can act in different ways on that. For example you could need to perform resizing on your images (things that you could do with gems like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)), but you don't need to do this on video or audio.

Comment: Oh wow cool thanks I really like that But even still Since I have multiple parent models, should I take advantage of the opportunity to have multiple image models for each to lighten the load on my database server by not giving it such a large table to have to select from

Comment: Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498217/what-is-considered-a-large-table-in-sql-server) question.